# css - align side by side 3 divs of different sizes

Tags: html

I want to obtain this fixed-size table:
[image]

What I tried:

```
<div class="my-container">

    <div class="left"></div>

    <div class="middle"></div>

    <div class="right">  </div>

</div>


.my-container{
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}


.left{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

[image]

The result is that I have some space between elements, and my container's size is not exactly equal to the sum of its tree children. I would like to make three children match perfectly with my-container.

Comment: you have to remove display:inline-block; in all three object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: flex;` on `my-container` and remove `inline-block` from child elements

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <div class="left"></div>

  <div class="middle"></div>

  <div class="right"> </div>

</div>
```

**OR**
Add `font-size: 0;` on `my-container` element. And add font-size on the divs inside it if it has text in it.

```css
.my-container {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 0;
}

.my-container div {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">

  <div class="left"></div>

  <div class="middle"></div>

  <div class="right"> </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can, I would suggest using [Nandita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51400074/1650337), however if you can't use flexbox layout for some reason (e.g. [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)):

The spaces are caused by whitespace in the HTML file, this can be resolved in a couple of ways.

- Remove the whitespace

```css
.my-container {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.middle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="left"></div><!-- These comments "remove" the whitespace without breaking your code formatting too badly
  --><div class="middle"></div><!--
  --><div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

- Set the `font-size` to 0 on the container

```css
.my-container {
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 0; /* Make the whitespace take up no actual space */
}

.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 16px; /* Make sure to set the font back to normal on the children */
}

.middle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"> </div>
</div>
```